# Get part of a table into a div

Tags: jquery, html

Using jQuery, how would I go about getting part of a vanilla table (no ids or classes) into a div element? The table is a simple lunch menu with days of the week in it's own th element followed by a break, lunch, and dessert with respective descriptions of each in their own td element. I would like to grab everything between Monday and Tuesday, Tuesday and Wednesday, and so on.

Here is a sample table I'm [working with](http://jsfiddle.net/jawa9000/msbDc/).

```
<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>breakfast</th>
    <td>cereal</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lunch</th>
    <td>hamburger</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>dessert</th>
    <td>cake</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>breakfast</th>
    <td>bagel</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lunch</th>
    <td>chicken</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>dessert</th>
    <td>cookie</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>breakfast</th>
    <td>eggs</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>lunch</th>
    <td>sandwich</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>dessert</th>
    <td>pie</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What part is giving you trouble? Where are you stuck? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to grab everything between Monday and Tuesday,

Well, Monday is row 0 and Tuesday is row 5. So [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) would probably relate:

```
var rows = $("selector-for-the-table tr").slice(1, 6);
// Get the info from `rows`
```

So for example: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/msbDc/1/)

```
var rows = $("table tr").slice(1, 6);
display("Selected data:");
rows.each(function() {
    display($(this).find("td").text());
});


function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(String(msg)).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

Which gives us:

```
Selected data:
cereal
hamburger
cake
```

Comment: This is great! I'm gonna try both yours and Jay Blanchard's answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way - http://jsfiddle.net/msbDc/4/

```
var start = $('table th:contains(Monday)').parent().index();
var end = $('table th:contains(Tuesday)').parent().index();
console.log(start +' '+ end);
var myRows = $('tr').slice(start, end).clone();

$('div').html(myRows);
$('div tr').wrapAll('<table border="1"></table>');
```

Based on comments from the OP I have updated the fiddle and the code - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/msbDc/5/

```
var start = $('table th:contains(Monday)').parent().index();
var end = $('table th:contains(Thursday)').parent().index();
console.log(start +' '+ end);
if(-1 == end) { // if the endpoint doesn't exist, get everything from start to end.
    var myRows = $('tr').slice(start).clone();
} else {
    var myRows = $('tr').slice(start, end).clone();
}
```

Comment: This is great! I'm gonna try both yours and T.J's solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome. I like this method because you don't have to figure out the index numbers. You could replace 'Monday' and 'Tuesday' with variables whose value you could set with some other method.

Comment: Thanks again! I just tried this out on my test page and it works very well with the bigger picture project I'm working on.

Comment: Actually, it works great for grabbing the first day when I try swapping Monday-Tuesday with Tuesday-Wednesday in the respective start and end variables, it doesn't grab the requested days and content. :/

Comment: Think about it - selecting Monday / Tuesday gets Monday. Selecting Tuesday / Wednesday will get Tuesday. That's because the endpoint (Wednesday) acts just like the Tuesday endpoint in the first example - it is the place where the slicing ends. You would have to remove the 'end' variable from the `slice()` if you want to pick a a starting point that gets everything to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help Jay. I ended up going with something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < menuDays.length; i++) { // Sunday - Saturday array
        if (i > 0 && i < 6) { // skip Sunday and Saturday
            start = $("table th:contains(" + menuDays[i] + ")").parent().index();
            if (i == 5) {
                end = $("table th:contains(Friday)").parent().siblings().length + 1;
            } else {
                end = $("table th:contains(" + menuDays[i + 1] + ")").parent().index();
            }
            rows = $("#foodTable tr").slice(start + 1, end).clone();
            $("#foodOption" + menuDays[i]).html(rows);
            $("#foodOption" + menuDays[i] + " tr").wrapAll("<table></table>");
        }
    }
```